# How to access aws public dataset on S3?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-pig

I am trying to load public data using pig from s3 using this url
s3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/20090715/eng-us-all/4gram/data

LOAD 's3n://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/20090715/eng-us-all/4gram/data'

but it is asking for access and secret key. Should I move this data to one of my buckets? or am I missing something

Comment: even though the dataset is public, we need to add the following policy to the IAM role 
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1452869694000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::datasets.elasticmapreduce/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Public data sets are also accessible only when you have AWS account. Data sets are visible to every one on AWS. Hence you need to pass credentials - access key and secret key in this case.

Comment: The public dataset on S3 is .lzo compressed and is a sequence file. Any recommendations on how to process it using PIG ?

Comment: Here is the example: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201405.mbox/%3CCAOZaVw=4kLaziB4Hk8rM6YVHRSWzJ-Uk_9nL-mW-aYBeAGiV7g@mail.gmail.com%3E